# how to exit this loop in python

Tags: python, loops

why does break doesn't work? I want the code to stop when I click the specific key

```
import keyboard


def loop():
    x = 1
    while True:
        print(x)
        x = x+1


while True:
    if keyboard.is_pressed('q'):
        print("q pressed")
        break
    loop()
```

Comment: Your infinite loop inside the `loop()` function does not have a break in it.

Comment: `if keyboard.is_pressed('q')` is only checked at the start of the program, then `while True` inside `loop()` is entered at it stays there forever.

Comment: What program do you wish to make? A counter/stopwatch which runs till you press `q`?

Comment: @Abhyuday Vaish i want stop the loop when i press the q key
i tried 'if not' didn't work also

Comment: @AymenHmani Why are you running `loop()` infinitely? You need to add a break in `loop()`

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are in the function loop(). There is no break statement in the loop. Maybe try this?

```
import keyboard


def loop():
    x = 1
    while True:
        print(x)
        x = x+1
        if keyboard.is_pressed('q'):
            print("q pressed")
            break
    

      
loop()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because the break isn't inside the loop (function), to fix this we put the condition inside the desired loop.

```py
import keyboard


def loop():
    x = 1
    while True:
        if keyboard.is_pressed('q'):
            print("q pressed")
            break
        print(x)
        x = x+1


while True:
    loop()
```

I presume the second loop is necessary, to not close the program.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can just simply solve the error just by making 1 change.

Just delete the while True command in last when you call `loop()` function. That is the only thing that is causing an issue.

```
import keyboard
    
    def loop():
        x = 1
        while True:
            if keyboard.is_pressed("q"):
                print("\n q pressed")
                break
            print(x)
            x = x+1
    
    loop()
```

FYI: You can add some delay if you want counts to slow down. For that you will have to import time library.